# I have to specify UnityEngine before Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to use the Input Class in Unity I get the error *"'Input' does not contain a definition for 'GetButton'"* or 'GetButtonDown' or similar errors.

not working code vvv

```
using UnityEngine;
    
If (Input.GetButtonDown("Button"))
        {
            Do something here;
        }
```

To fix it I have to type in "UnityEngine." before "Input," even though I am already using UnityEngine.

working code vvv

```
using UnityEngine;
    
If (UnityEngine.Input.GetButtonDown("Button"))
        {
            Do something here;
        }
```

This happened after I tried using the new unity input system and reverting back, after some problems.

Comment: Based on the error a different class called `Input` was found in some other namespace, but it doesn't contain a method called `GetButtonDown()`. You have to find which of your imported namespaces contains such a class and either remove it from your `using` list, or if that's not an option, simply continue using the fully qualified name.

Comment: Also make sure that you haven't created any classes of your own called `Input`, as the current namespace takes precedence over the imported ones.